# How can I use a python Set as the column labels in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

When trying to create a DataFrame in Pandas 1.5, I get the error `ValueError: index cannot be a set`.  I tried to create the DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns=set(["a", "b", "c"]))
```

Comment: Not reproducible; you code runs just fine.

Comment: It is broken as of the latest version - I self-posted an answer

Comment: You should be able to accept your answer if you have solved your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Pandas recently had an update (as of version 1.5) which disallows the creation of DataFrames using set indices.  This was a breaking change, so that code which worked before may no longer work on Pandas versions 1.5 or higher.  See the GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/47215).

You can fix this by converting the set to a list, with e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])
```

Comment: Converting a set to a list doesn't fix the deeper issue, which is that sets are unordered. The conversion to list will impose an order based on the set's hash table indices, which is likely to be completely different from the order you wanted. This means you'll get the wrong column labels.

Comment: The real fix is to use a list from the start, and not bring sets in at all.